# Understanding type of gradient descent and how its calculated in Pytorch framework and making it more dynamic

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, hyperparameters

I recently started implementing Neural network using pytorch framework and here is my code:

```
      class NN(nn.Module):

         def __init__(self):
            super(NN,self).__init__()
            self.f1 = nn.Linear(1,h)#,bias = False) 
            self.f2 = nn.Linear(h,1)#,bias = False)
         def forward(self,x):
            x = self.f1(x)
            x = f.relu(x)
            x = self.f2(x)
            return x

     model = NN()
     loss_type = nn.MSELoss()


     optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

     l = []
     for i in range(epochs):
        y_pred = model.forward(X_train)

        loss = loss_type(y_pred,Y_train)
        l.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I have few questions related to this:

(`1`) Is it updating weights at every data point/training example that is stoachastic gradient decsent (SGD) or its averaging weight and then updating at every epoc.?

(`2`) Why this `super(NN,self).__init__()` is used?

(`3`) Instead of passing `x = f.relu(x)`, can I make it more dynamic like for an example can I dynamically pass following parameters keeping the same architecture and running the model for every combination and storing the result or loss for every combination.

```
  { hiddenLayer=[10,20,30],activation_function=['sigmoid','relu'],learning rate=[0.1,0.2], epoc=[10,20,30] }

   How can I modify the above code to implement this. So that everytime I do not have to change my hyperparemeters.
```

(`4`) What does the `NN.parameters` contain. How to get dictionary having every layer weights and biases using this?

Thanks!